# ¿Como invertir Bytes de un entero en java?

Tags: java

Tengo que recorrer un rango de IPs, el problema es que el formato que la función devuelve está invertido. El formato que devuelve la función es:

Primera IP

```
108736
00000000 00000001 10101000 11000000
       0        1      168      192
```

Última IP

```
-16668480
11111111 00000001 10101000 11000000
     255        1      168      192
```

Lo que quiero es que queden:

```
192.168.1.0      3232235776
192.168.1.255    3232236031
```

Esto para poder recorrerlas en un ciclo.

**Edit**

El for es este:

```
for (int i = getNetworkIp(c) + 1, bc = getBroadCastIp(c); i < bc; i++) { 
    if (isReachable(intToIp(i))) { 
        ips += "ip " + intToIp(i) + " encontrada\n";
    }
}
```

El problema es que al hacer el ciclo me queda desde: 108736 hasta -16668480

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código que tienes actualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede utilizar `Integer.reverseBytes`:

```
int numBytesReversed = Integer.reverseBytes(num);
```

También hay `Integer.reverseque` invierte todos los **bits** de una **int**

```
int numBitsReversed = Integer.reverse(num);
java.lang.Integer vínculos de API

public static int reverseBytes(int i)
```

Devuelve el valor obtenido mediante la inversión del orden de los **bytes** en representación de complemento a dos del valor int especificado.

```
public static int reverse(int i)
```

Devuelve el valor obtenido mediante la inversión del orden de los bits en la representación binaria de complemento a dos del valor **int** especificado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer es convertir la "[endianess](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)".

```
/* convierte de big-endian a little-endian y viceversa */
public static int convertEndianess(int i) {
    return (i & 0xff) << 24 | (i & 0xff00) << 8 | (i & 0xff0000) >> 8 | (i >> 24) & 0xff;
}

/* interpreta un int como unsigned, y lo devuelve como long */
public static long intToUnsignedAsLong(int x) {
    return ((long) x) & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ip = 108736;
    int ip2 = convertEndianess(ip);
    System.out.println(intToUnsignedAsLong(ip2));
}
```

Esto imprime `3232235776`
Notese que normalmente la conversion a `long` (para verlo como `unsigned`) no es para nada necesaria o deseable - si omitimos eso, el número resultante es `-1062731520`